# What does "hold load for" mean in jmeter, and how do I disable it?

Tags: jmeter

In the stepping and ultimate thread group, there is an option that says "hold load for". What does this mean?

From what I've read, it seems to repeat the thread in a loop within the set amount of time? What if I set it to 0 seconds? Does that mean a thread won't execute each of its http requests?

I don't want it to hold, but I do need the features of stepping thread.

Answer (score 2):

Hold load means its duration of your running test if we say in simple language. Suppose if you specify 30 user and hold load = 60 seconds then your test will run continue till 60 seconds and it will stop automatically after 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have selected hold load for 60 seconds.
And your test scenario is 30 users trying to log in.
Then all these users will try to login for as many times as possible for the time span of 60 seconds.
To verify this look in to the result tree and calculate how many login attempts happened during that period.

Comment: I think the important part of the OP's question is, "What if I set it to 0 seconds... I don't want it to hold."